# Deploying ASP.NET 5 app to EC2 in a Docker container

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker, asp.net-core

I have a t2.micro EC2 instance running Amazon Linux AMI 2015.03.1.  I [installed docker](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html) on it, but then also [updated it](https://docs.docker.com/installation/binaries/) manually. Finally, I made the docker daemon listen on a port of my choosing so I could publish to it remotely.

On my development machine, I added to my VS2015 install the [VS2015 Tools for Docker - August Preview](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0f5b2caa-ea00-41c8-b8a2-058c7da0b3e4).  I added a new ASP.NET 5 Web Application, built it and hit publish.  The container makes it to the host, but it never runs because of this exception;

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.IConfigurationRoot' from assembly 'Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.String[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.Program.ExecuteMain (Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.DefaultHost host, System.String applicationName, System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.String[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Bootstrapper.RunAsync (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 args, IRuntimeEnvironment env, System.Runtime.Versioning.FrameworkName targetFramework) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue due to multiple projects references different versions of ASP.NET5 - ie; beta7 & beta6.

Ensuring only one stream was referenced in all project.json's resolved this issue.